# Can i Detect if .text() is called on a button?

Tags: jquery

Suppose i have the following html:

```
<button class="inforTextButton" id"myButton">
   <span class="leftSlice"></span>
   <span class="centerSlice">Approved</span>
   <span class="rightSlice"></span>
</button>
```

If i call the following command in jQuery:

```
$("#myButton").text("New Text");
```

It will replace all the spans with the text.

Is there anyway to detect this event? What i would like to do at that time is prevent it from replacing all the contents and instead change the centerSlice.

Now I know i could call: `$("#myButton").find(".centerSlice").text("New Text")` but thats not what exactly the point of my question. In case in the future my button implementation changes and I am trying to see if this is possible in some way to detect which i am missing..

I tried textchange - seems like this does not fire on buttons.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you both. The following seems to be working nicely so far my only concern is the new function in jQuery..I cant assume a copy of jquery for my case..    `$.fn.baseText = $.fn.text;
 $.fn.text = function (text) { 
  /* jQuery function to change the centerSlice text */ 
  var centerslice=this.children(".centerSlice");
  if (centerslice.length>0) {
   centerslice.text(text);
   return this;
  }
  else {
   return this.baseText(text)
  }
 };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text function is stored in `$.fn.text` this means what you can do is replace that function:

```
var oldTextFunc = $.fn.text;
$.fn.text = function newTextFunc(text) { 
    /* jQuery function to change the centerSlice text */ 
};
```

If you want to revert the jQuery text function:

```
$.fn.text = oldTextFunc;
```

Comment: Any way to call the original text function from within if not a button cant't seem to work that out. And although sub seems cool i cant work on a copy of jQuery in the instance of the case i am trying to solve.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with your first sentence, but you could probably use `.apply` or use `$.fn.oldTextFunc = $.fn.text;` instead of my the `var oldTextFunc = $.fn.text;` and just call `$('.selector').oldTextFunc();`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect use of [`.sub()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/), this would allow you create a copy of jQuery and override the default behavior for `.text()`

```
var myjQuery = jQuery.sub();

myjQuery.fn.text = function() {

    if (this.is("button")) {
        alert("do something special with button");
    }
    else {
        return jQuery.fn.text.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
myjQuery("#myButton").text("New Text");​
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fBrad/1/)**

Comment: Wow thanks for a quick answer... I was starting to look for a safe way to override the functions but wasnt aware of the best way to do it.

Comment: Should i be concerned that: This method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and will be moved to a plugin in jQuery 1.8?

Comment: Note that all of your code will need to use this copy of jquery.  Any code using the real jquery will bypass your override of `text`.